# Bar and line graphs overlaying on same figure, containing groups, and by another group

Tags: data-visualization, stata

I am attempting to create a figure that essentially has a bar graph corresponding to one group and a line graph for another group, but where there are two groups within each of the formerly described groups. I have tried various ways of using twoway and binscatter but have not been able to achieve what I would like.

I am including a picture of what I would like to create: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdO1W.png

I imagine it might take some reshaping, but it might not. If anyone has any leads, I would definitely appreciate it. If color could be left to the user's desire, that would be even better. Although I think the data is shaped so that one could create the graph "automatically" by referring to the categories, it might be possible to reshape the data and use county-year as the categorical variable.

The code to develop the dataset:

```
clear
set obs 16
g month = _n
g year = 2000
replace year = 2010 if month > 8
g cost = runiform(0, 100)
g country = "USA" if _n <= 4
replace country = "China" if _n > 4 & _n <= 8
replace country = "USA" if _n > 8 & _n <= 12
replace country = "China" if _n > 12 & _n <= 16
replace month = month - 4 if month>4 & month<=8
replace month = month - 8 if month>8 & month<=12
replace month = month - 12 if month>12 & month<=16
```

Comment: I recommend re-posting on Statalist or Stack Overflow with a clearer explanation of what should be lines and what should be bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in my view off-topic on CV -- please see advice on software-related questions in the Help Center -- but while I am waiting to see if others also vote that way I find the question unclear in any case. The following won't fit well in a comment.

Here is a shorter equivalent of your code, and I set the seed for reproducibility.

```
clear
set seed 1234 
set obs 16
g year = cond(_n > 8, 2010, 2000) 
bysort year: g country = cond(_n > 4, "China", "USA")  
bysort year country : gen month = _n 
g cost = runiform(0, 100)

list , sepby(year country)

     +-----------------------------------+
     | year   country   month       cost |
     |-----------------------------------|
  1. | 2000     China       1   94.72316 |
  2. | 2000     China       2   5.222337 |
  3. | 2000     China       3   97.43183 |
  4. | 2000     China       4   94.57484 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  5. | 2000       USA       1   18.56478 |
  6. | 2000       USA       2   94.87334 |
  7. | 2000       USA       3   88.25376 |
  8. | 2000       USA       4   94.40776 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  9. | 2010     China       1   8.942585 |
 10. | 2010     China       2   75.05445 |
 11. | 2010     China       3   94.84983 |
 12. | 2010     China       4   11.21626 |
     |-----------------------------------|
 13. | 2010       USA       1   48.09064 |
 14. | 2010       USA       2   97.63448 |
 15. | 2010       USA       3   12.54975 |
 16. | 2010       USA       4   76.55025 |
     +-----------------------------------+
```

Your sketch has some data points joined by lines and some shown by bars, but there is here just one response variable `cost`, so I am at a loss to understand the logic there.